# How can i get my ReactJS project to display Unity 3D Game? I've tried react unity WEBGL

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine

I just finished coding a website with a Virtual Tour made on Unity, i've exported it as WEBGL with compression format disabled, and decompression fallback off(Unity). Then added this to my code on React

```
import React from "react";
import Unity, { UnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";

const unityContext = new UnityContext({
  loaderUrl: "../Build/unity341.loader.js",
  dataUrl: "../Build/unity341.data",
  frameworkUrl: "../Build/unity.framework.js",
  codeUrl: "../Build/unity341.wasm",
});

function Game() {
    return <Unity unityContext={unityContext} />;
  }

  export default Game;
```

then imported the game on the page

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Game from './game.jsx';
import {Container} from 'react-bootstrap';

class GamePage extends Component {
render() {
return ( 
  <div>
    <Game/>
  <Container>
//text and stuff inside the container
</Container>
</div>
);
}
}


export default GamePage;
```

But when i render it on my localhost i dont get the Unity viewer, and when inspecting on Chrome the only thing i see where the game should be is the following tag

```
<canvas class>
```

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 1):

Put generated `WebGL files` from `Build` folder to `public` folder in react. See picture. Those files must be in public folder because react server is hosting static files in this folder. For example i have put them to `public\build` folder. See picture.

[image]

Code in react:

```
const unityContext = new UnityContext({
    loaderUrl: 'build/<AppName>.loader.js',
    dataUrl: 'build/<AppName>.data',
    frameworkUrl: 'build/<AppName>.framework.js',
    codeUrl: 'build/<AppName>.wasm',
});
```

```
<Unity unityContext={unityContext} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
```